# regex for even no. of single quotes

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find 'AND' followed by even no. of single(') quotes and replace it with 'OR', I am trying it in java using regex but no luck so far

```
e.g.  company='sam"'"s AND joseph"'"s' AND year='1998'
      EXPECTED output: company=' sam"'"s AND joseph"'"s ' OR year='1998'
```

single quotes within double quotes are not to be considered while counting for even no. of single quotes.So in the above output first 'and' remains intact and second one gets replaced by 'or'

Comment: no luck so far? Show it

Comment: do you have examples of the regexp you've tried and their output?

Comment: all your sentence are same ?

Comment: Isn't the first `AND` followed by 4 quotes?

Comment: @aelor, the second sentence has OR in it which is not there in first one.

Comment: @Robin, the single quotes within the double quotes are to be ignored, so if we see that way then the first AND is just followed by one 'single' quote(which accounts for odd no. of quote) hence need not be replaced by 'OR' but the second 'AND' is preceded by 2 single quotes(as we are not considering single quotes within double quotes) hence needs to be replaced

Comment: @user3266530 What regex implementation is this? PHP? C#? Java? Perl? Javascript?

Comment: @h2000000  its java , i hava mentioned I am trying it in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the following regex (count only `'` not preceded by `"`).

```
\bAND\b(?=(?:(?:[^']*[^'"]'){2})*[^']*$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6Xf8GZXHaS1CcMNu)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,It works well in the above case but fails in this case: company='sam"'"s AND joseph"'"s' AND year=1998,as the value of year is not within the quotes

Comment: @user3266530 I updated the answer, added option for trailing text with no `'`.

Comment: its working but its failing in one case: company='sam"'"s AND joseph"'"s' AND year='1998' AND age=20, the output now is :company='sam"'"s and joseph"'"s' AND year='1998' OR age=80, ONE AND IS STILL THERE,after the year in quotes there is age without quotes

Answer (score 0):

user3266530, I am not sure I fully understand your requirement of "an even number of single quotes" after the AND. Am I wrong in assuming that you are looking for `AND` followed somewhere by a `'single-quoted string'` (but these strings cannot be quoted)?

If this is what you want, I suggest the following regex:

Search: `\bAND\b(.*?(?!"'").'[^\s']*)'`

Replace: `OR\1'`

**How does this work?**

1. We match the word AND (set off by two word boundaries `\b` to avoid ANDREW and AMPERSAND)
2. The parentheses start capture Group 1
3. We lazily eat up characters with `.*?` until a position x where the second next character is a single quote (as shown later by the match `.'`) At position x, to avoid `"'"` the negative lookahead `(?!"'")` asserts that what follows is not `"'"`
4. We match the next character, the opening single quote, then `[^\s']` matches any number of characters that are not a whitespace character or a single quote
5. We close the Group 1 parens
6. For balance, we match the closing single quote
7. We replace the whole match with OR followed by the Group 1 capture followed by a single quote

Please note that `[^\s']` has assumed that you don't have spaces `'withinYourSingleQuotes
But if there is a possibility that you might do, remove the`\s`so that the character class becomes`[^']`i.e. "any character that is not a single quote. You still need the quantifier`*` at the end.

**Some Java code to replace all the strings (in response to your comment):**

```
try {
    String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?s)\\bAND\\b(.*?(?!\"'\").'[^\\s']*)'", "OR\\1'");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the replacement text (unescaped $ signs?)
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // Non-existent backreference used the replacement text
}
```

Comment: the english sentence is like this, sam's and joseph's , which I am using in java like this: sam"'"s AND joseph"'"s ,the aphostrophe is surrounded by double quotes. Now while parsing this I don't want the apostrophe to be counted as single quoted(as it is within double quote) other than this all the single quotes should be counted.

Comment: @user3266530 Then I think what I sent you will work. I'll edit the question to explain how it works.

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately its not working(i am doing in java),thanks for trying.

Comment: @user3266530 I added some Java code at the bottom of my answer. Please let me know if this fixes the problem. :)

Comment: thanx again for trying but unfortunately its not working this time also, though I got my answer now, thank you for trying.